# dropdown load on selection of other dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have the dropdown trigger an ajax post that sends the selected value of country dropdown .

```
       model class

        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;

        namespace MVC_4___A_Registration_Form.Models
        {
            public class ModelServices
            {
                private readonly MyCompanyEntities entities = new MyCompanyEntities();

                public IEnumerable<Country> GetCountryList()
                {
                    return entities.Countries.ToList();
                }

                public IEnumerable<countryState> GetStateByCountry(int CountryID)
                {
                    return entities.countryStates.Where(s => s.CountryId == CountryID).ToList();
                }

                public IList<EmployeeRegInfo> GetAllEmployeeList()
                {
                    var myQuery = (from e in entities.Employees
                                   join c in entities.Countries on e.Country equals c.CountryId
                                   join s in entities.countryStates on e.State equals s.StateId
                                   select new EmployeeRegInfo()
                                   {
                                       Id = e.Id,
                                       Emp_ID = e.Emp_ID,
                                       Dept = e.Dept,
                                       Name = e.Name,
                                       CountryName = c.County,
                                       StateName = s.State,
                                       City = e.City,
                                       Mobile = e.Mobile
                                   });

                    return myQuery.ToList();
                }

                public bool IsEmpAlreadyExist(string EMP_CODE)
                {
                    bool IsRecordExist = false;

                    var result = (from t in entities.Employees
                                  where t.Emp_ID == EMP_CODE
                                  select t).SingleOrDefault();

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        IsRecordExist = true;
                    }
                    return IsRecordExist;
                }

                public void AddNewEmployee(Employee emp)
                {
                    entities.Employees.Add(emp);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

    create.cshtml

    @model MVC_4___A_Registration_Form.Models.EmployeeRegInfo
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @ViewBag.ErrorMsg
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Emp_ID)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Emp_ID)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emp_ID)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dept)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dept)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dept)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.Country as SelectList, new { Styles = "width:300px" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="State" name="State" style="width: 200px"></select>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile)</td>

                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Employee" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Country").change(function () {
                var url = "/ManageEmployee/GetStatesByCountry";
                var countryID = $("#Country").val();
                $.post(url, { countryID: countryID }, function (data) {
                    $("#State").empty();
                    var items;
                    $.each(data, function (i, states) {
                        items += "<option value=" + states.StateId + ">" + states.State + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#State").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

 controller

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MVC_4___A_Registration_Form.Models;

    namespace MVC_4___A_Registration_Form.Controllers
    {
        public class ManageEmployeeController : Controller
        {
            ModelServices model = new ModelServices();

            //
            // GET: /ManageEmployee/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                IList<EmployeeRegInfo> empList = new List<EmployeeRegInfo>();
                empList = model.GetAllEmployeeList();
                return View(empList);
            }

            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                IEnumerable<Country> country;
                country = model.GetCountryList();
                ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(country, "CountryId", "County", "CountryId");
                        return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
            {
                bool checkEmpCodeExist = false;
                checkEmpCodeExist = model.IsEmpAlreadyExist(collection["Emp_ID"]);
                if (!checkEmpCodeExist)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Employee emp = new Employee();
                        emp.Emp_ID = collection["Emp_ID"];
                        emp.Name = collection["Name"];
                        emp.Dept = collection["Dept"];
                        emp.Country = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Country"]);
                        emp.State = Convert.ToInt32(collection["State"]);
                        emp.City = collection["City"];
                        emp.Mobile = collection["Mobile"];
                        model.AddNewEmployee(emp);

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Employee Code Already Exist";
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }

            }

            public JsonResult GetStatesByCountry(int id)
            {
                var states = model.GetStateByCountry(id);
                return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }

I want to load state dropdown on selection of country dropdown.But i am unable to do this.
```

Please help to load state dropdown on selection of country dropdown.

```
I want to load state dropdown on selection of country dropdown.But i am unable to do this.
```

Please help to load state dropdown on selection of country dropdown.

Comment: What is the problem? What errors are you getting? You have not explained anything - just dumped a whole lot of code, most of which is not related to your question. - Spend some time reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and learn how to ask a question, and ho to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: for understanding i had dumped all code no other reason .very simple question whenever i select country from country drop down related state should be bind in state drop down .Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Hey I got the answer
    some change in ajax code and controller

      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Country").change(function () {
                var url = "/ManageEmployee/GetStatesByCountry";
                var countryID = $("#Country").val();
             $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { id: countryID },
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var markup = "<option value='0'>Select City</option>";
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                            markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                        }
                        $("#State").html(markup).show();
                    },
                    error: function (reponse) {
                        alert("error : " + reponse);
                    }
                });
            });

        });



  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetStatesByCountry(string id)
        {
            int ids = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            var states = model.GetStateByCountry(ids);
           SelectList obgcity = new SelectList(states, "StateId", "State", 0);
            return Json(obgcity);
        }
```